# Emulating usb device with a file using g_mass_storage => udc-core: couldn't find an available UDC - added [g_mass_storage] to list of pending drivers

Tags: kernel-modules

I would like to emulate an USB from an image file.

I am using Centos7 with the **Kernel 4.11.7** installed through `kernel-ml` and `kernel-ml-devel` **elrepo** `4.11.7-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64` (actually I tried with 3.10.* 4.10.* 4.11.1 too)

We have 2 solutions:

1. with **insmod**

   sudo insmod /link/to/g_mass_storage.ko file=/tmp/filebin.img stall=0 removable=y

In **dmesg**:
`udc-core: couldn't find an available UDC - added [g_mass_storage] to list of pending drivers`

2. with **modprobe**

   $ sudo modprobe g_mass_storage file=/tmp/testusb.img stall=0 removable=y 
   modprobe: FATAL: Module g_mass_storage not found.
   Nothing in **dmesg**.
3. I have also tried with **dummy_hcd**:

   $ sudo modprobe dummy_hcd
   modprobe: FATAL: Module dummy_hcd not found.

**How can I fix this problem ?**

I tried many things like recompiling the Kernel 4.11.1 by enabling everything with gadget etc...

```
/usr/src/kernels/4.11.7-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 $ cat .config | grep CONFIG_USB_DUMMY_HCD
# CONFIG_USB_DUMMY_HCD is not set
```

**Result:**
After compiling the kernel, I was able to `modprobe dummy_hcd` and to emulate an usb with a binary file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the `dummy_hcd` dummy (loopback) host controller device. The gadget USB drivers are meant for real USB hardware, and on normal PCs this hardware doesn't exist. The loopback controller provides both the framework for the gadget controller, and a USB host controller to access them. So:

```
$ sudo modprobe dummy_hcd
```

gives you a new root hub

```
$ lsusb
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Now you can modprobe the gadget driver

```
$ sudo modprobe g_mass_storage file=/path/to/backing_file idVendor=0x1d6b idProduct=0x0104 iManufacturer=Myself iProduct=VirtualBlockDevice iSerialNumber=123
```

and it will show up under the new root hub

```
$ lsusb
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0525:a4a5 Netchip Technology, Inc. Pocketbook Pro 903
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Note that you don't need to simulate a USB mass storage device if you are just interested in the contents of the file, you can mount that directly (via the loop device, but that happens automatically).

Comment: I forgot to say I tried `dummy_hcd`  too. But : `modprobe: FATAL: Module dummy_hcd not found.` I don't know why I don't have this module.

Comment: Verify that `CONFIG_USB_DUMMY_HCD=m`, and set and recompile if it isn't.

Comment: It's not, Im gonna recompile. I'll let you keep informed. Thanks.

Comment: It's working, thank you ! Btw how to "eject" the usb without rebooting ?

Comment: `sudo modprobe -r g_mass_storage` works.